# Is this a valid configuration for decoupling capacitors on an IC with two supply pins?

Tags: pcb-design, decoupling-capacitor, expander

I have a project that's using an IC that only comes in SMD packages.  With my limited soldering experience, I think I could potentially solder a TSSOP, but I think QFN is well beyond my capabilities.

I decide to try to make a PCB that adapts the TSSOP to a DIP profile compatible with common breadboards.

This particular IC ([NXP PCAL6416A](https://www.nxp.com/products/analog/interfaces/ic-bus/ic-general-purpose-i-o/low-voltage-translating-16-bit-ic-bus-smbus-i-o-expander:PCAL6416A)) has two supply pins, one for the I2C bus and one for the GPIO ports (this is an IO expander).

Would this capacitor placement and configuration potentially work for decoupling my two supply pins?  Would it be a problem if both pins are on the same supply line vs. different ones?

This is the PCB layout:

[image: PCB layout]

This is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

Thanks very much!

Edit:

In case other hobbyists come across this question and would be helped by a visual representation of the answer, here's the latest implementation I have based on my understanding of the solution:

[image]

Comment: Normally what you have would be minimal. Adding 4.7uF MMC capacitors somewhat close to the IC helps to filter lower frequency noise. They must have low ESR specs to be useful.

Comment: It is a very sub-optimal layout. Since you have a 2-layer board, dedicate one layer to mostly ground, place C2 below the IC, and ground C1 with via. Same supply or different -  it doesn't matter. But currently both bypass caps share a very long common trace, and a sizable cross-talk between two rails is guaranteed.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I'd argue that in this board, having a ground plane on the top layer and the caps on that same layer would be advantageous to avoid via inductance, since the IC pinout allows for caps to be placed very near to the pins (shift U1 slightly to the right, so that C2 fits left of it). Bottom ground plane is of course the way to go, no matter what you do.

Comment: D.Patrick, are you sure INT even needs to be routed on the bottom? Having an uninterrupted ground plane is always nice, and if you pick 0805 for your caps, you should have enough "bridge" to route it between pads – that is, if the signal is robust enough not to be disturbed by the crosstalk from power pins (would be a good idea to do that below the low-current I²C cap).

Comment: @MarcusMüller why don't you post as an Answer ?

Comment: @Damien I've worked on my shyness.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for making this world a better place.

Comment: The unaligned outline bothers me _a lot_! Please use the grid when drawing the outline!

Comment: @pipe, thanks!  I didn't notice that and would've been super frustrated!  I actually did use the grid.  I like having curved corners (because I'm weird like that).  I drew all of the corners first and then connected them with segments.  Kicad has you place the center first, draw the radius, and then the arc.  I put the center point in the wrong spot.  Is there an easier way to draw the edge cuts with rounded corners?  On a previous board, I did draw a rectangle and then inscribed the corners.  I had to redraw the edges after that, but it made it easy to keep all of the lines at right angles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much anywhere, ground planes are desirable. Your km-long GND trace is no good! There will be plenty of inductance here, and the fact that you connect the two capacitors more in series between the two supply pins than in parallel to ground means that there will be coupling of noise from one to the other supply pin!

This looks like Kicad, so use the Zone tool to define a plane in the GND net, on both the top and bottom layer of the board, covering the full area of the board.

Your goal is to get the capacitors as close as possible to the supply pins. So, move them directly adjacent to the IC package.

Instead of routing INT on the bottom layer, simply route the VDDI2C right of the pad (i.e. below the package, but on the top layer) and simply route the INT between the holes of the pin header. That way, you get a continous ground plane on the bottom.

Throw in a dozen or two of ground-plane-stitching vias between the bottom and top ground plane.

As @Sparky256 [pointed out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415317/is-this-a-valid-configuration-for-decoupling-capacitors-on-an-ic-with-two-supply?noredirect=1#comment1027234_415317), for chips that switch fast or high currents, you basically can't have too much capacitance stabilizing the power supply. So, add some additional capacitance – Sparky recommends 4.7 µF multilayer ceramic, but if that's too expensive or hard to get, I've had good experience with 1 µF ceramic + 10 µF (or more) *low-ESR* electrolytic / tantalum.

Comment: Considering that this is just an I/O expander with maximum currents of 20mA and being controlled via rather slow I2C, 4.7uF or 10uF is a bit overkill.

Comment: Thanks very much for your responses. I’m updating the PCB so I can put your changes in an edit to my question (so that once it’s better, other newbies like me can see the difference visually).  I have to manually add stitching vias in Kicad I think. How do I decide where to put them?

Comment: @EdgarBrown, that kind of brings up a dumb question I’ve had for a while now. If I added pads for a cap in parallel with the .1 uF, just in case but never solder anything to it, would that be bad?  I guess I mean, is it bad to put a spot for a capacitor because I don’t know if I need it or not?  Thanks!

Comment: @D.Patrick unpopulated parts are rather common for many reasons. As long as placing them does not lead to problematic compromises, e.g., adding excessive trace parasitics due to increased part separation, then there would be no issues.

Comment: … and that wouldn't happen here, since this is a low-frequency circuit, not something in the upper MHzes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, now that I think about it, is “how do I know where to put stitching vias?” complex enough to warrant its own question?

Comment: yep, and aside from "if in doubt, add one", I honestly wouldn't know well! I'd be very interested in the answer to that question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller is it somewhat accurate to say, “I added a ground pour to the top and bottom layers of the board to make a low impedance connection between the decoupling capacitor and ground.  I understand that I need some stitching vias for best results, but how do I determine the best places to put them?”  Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks again for all of your help.  I've updated my question with the changes as I understood them.  Am I beginning to approach your recommendations (aside from the stitching vias)?

Comment: looks fine to me!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you're my hero!!  Here's the stitching via question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415421/how-do-i-know-where-to-put-stitching-vias

Answer (score 1):

Two important factors are ;

- external power sequencing synchronization
- on board ground plane for reducing inductance noise

This would look better.

[image]